# Django forms error - That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a custom messaging platform between users. For some reason it says that my form is not valid when I submit it, and when I print the error with print(messageform.errors), I get:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>receiver<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

This is strange because I don't believe that I'm using a dropdown anywhere in the form. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

forms.py

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['text', 'receiver']
```

html file

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="text" name="text" value="" />
     <label for="text">Enter your message here</label><br/>

     <input type="text" name="receiver" value="" />
     <label for="receiver">id of receiver</label><br/>

     <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

models.py

```
class Message(models.Model): 
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
                    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    null = True, 
                    related_name="sender"
                    )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(
                    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    null = True, 
                    related_name="receiver"
                    )
```

views.py

```
usermodel = get_user_model()

if request.method == "POST" and not signupform.is_valid():
        messageform = MessageForm(request.POST)
        print(messageform.errors)
        if messageform.is_valid():
            receiverid = messageform.cleaned_data['receiver']
            newmessage = messageform.save(commit=False)
            newmessage.sender = request.user
            newmessage.receiver = usermodel.objects.filter(username=receiverid)
            newmessage.text = messageform.cleaned_data['text']
            new_profile.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
```

Comment: That is default input type for `ForeignKey` field in django. You may want to add a field new `receiver` field in form as text input and then use it in view. Otherwise you can render the HTML input from form field which will show as drop down.

Comment: @Rohan I added the form field for receiver (charfield) and I'm getting the error - "Message.receiver" must be a "User" instance." Looking at my views.py, I thought that I was already rendering the HTML input from the form field. I'm setting newmessage.receiver to a usermodel (my custom User model, called User) object so I'm not sure why it's throwing that error